# Tratamento de valor null c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tenho um método que me gera um execption, como tratar isso?: agradeço

```
 public string CarregaProdutosDermaClube(string codigoproduto)
{
    //consulta os dados
    var tbuscar = new BuscaProdutosDermaClubeDAL();
    var retorno = tbuscar.ProdutoDermaClube(codigoproduto);

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(retorno.idproduto))
    {
        return "0";
    }
    else
    {
        return "1";
    }
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: `if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(retorno))
return retorno.idproduto; else return 0;` não ficaria agradavel?

Comment: Esse código ta gerando exception? Ou você quer que gere se for Null? No else não deveria retornar o conteúdo da var `retorno`? Ta bem confuso a pergunta.

Comment: Precisa verificar se o retorno é nulo primeiro. Poderia fazer algo assim: retorno?.idProduto

Comment: gerando exception

Comment: Usando o VS 2015

Comment: @ if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(retorno)) vou testar

Comment: Não deu certo, if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(retorno)) a única que funcionou foi  if (retorno != null) {}

Answer (score 1):

Utilizando if ternário

```
 public string CarregaProdutosDermaClube(string codigoproduto)
        {
            //consulta os dados
            return string.IsNullOrEmpty(new BuscaProdutosDermaClubeDAL().
                                 ProdutoDermaClube(codigoproduto)?.idproduto)? "0" : "1";
        }
```

Comment: Exatamente como eu faria.

Answer (score 0):

Se você estiver utilizando Visual Studio a partir da versão 2015:

```
public string CarregaProdutosDermaClube(string codigoproduto)
{
    //consulta os dados
    var tbuscar = new BuscaProdutosDermaClubeDAL();
    var retorno = tbuscar.ProdutoDermaClube(codigoproduto);

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(retorno?.idproduto))
    {
        return "0";
    }
    else
    {
        return "1";
    }
}
```

Em versões anteriores:

```
public string CarregaProdutosDermaClube(string codigoproduto)
{
    //consulta os dados
    var tbuscar = new BuscaProdutosDermaClubeDAL();
    var retorno = tbuscar.ProdutoDermaClube(codigoproduto);

    if (retorno == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(retorno.idproduto))
    {
        return "0";
    }
    else
    {
        return "1";
    }
}
```

Comment: Isso tem a ver com a versão da linguagem, não do Visual Studio.

Comment: De fato é verdade, mas é mais facil explicar assim do que fazer a pessoa identificar a versão do C# que está instalada no visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

Normalmente deve-se utilizar um bloco **try/catch** quando há troca de informações entre aplciações, no seu caso, entre seu software e o banco de dados. É também uma boa prática utilizar um framework de logs para gravar exceções geradas no seu sistema.

Outro ponto é o retorno do seu método, como ele retorna **"0"** ou **"1"** nada melhor que utilizar o tipo **bool** (true/false) indicando se o produto foi ou não carregado com sucesso.

```
 public bool CarregaProdutosDermaClube(string codigoproduto)
        {
            try
            {
                //consulta os dados
                var tbuscar = new BuscaProdutosDermaClubeDAL();
                var retorno = tbuscar.ProdutoDermaClube(codigoproduto);
                return retorno != null ? true : false;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // você pode logar a exceção capturada em "ex"
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Avaliando o código pode estar ocorrendo erro no caso da variável "retorno" = null.

Um exemplo para tratar essa situação é utilizar o ? antes do ".". Exemplo:

```
string idProduto = Convert.ToString(retorno?.idProduto);
```

Para leitura do código também sugiro utilizar o ternário, conforme já foi explicado nos comentários. Exemplo:

```
return string.IsNullOrEmpty(idProduto) ? "0" : "1";
```